# iText performance: Generate or populate pdf forms?

Tags: java, performance, pdf, itext

I want to write some text in a PDF file.

Approach 1: Using AcroForms.
To me, this the simplest approach. But we have some performance doubts. Using this approach, I'll be embedding a PDF template that contains  in my resources folder and populating already existing fields that I've already created in Acrobat like so:

```java
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
        form.setGenerateAppearance(true);
        form.getField("name")
                .setVisibility(PdfFormField.VISIBLE)
                .setReadOnly(true)
                .setValue("Hamza Belmellouki");
        // other fields being set
```

Approach 2: Generate the PDF from Scratch.
In this approach, I write the whole content to the file(Static content as well as dynamic one) and generate it.

In terms of performance, I am wondering which approach should we go with?

Comment: That depends on details. E.g. the ratio of static content to form fields, on the layout complexities, the form complexities, etc.

Comment: Our form is just simple text fields. The PDF file is only one page. Do you think working with form fields can have an impact on performance? We're really confused about which approach to take.

Comment: It would also depend on the intended output. I would assume you are producing a single file with a single document. If you are producing a huge package like 10000 invoices in one PDF, then using neither approach is best. The beat solution for this is a static PDF background and data stamped in specific places.

Comment: *"Our form is just simple text fields. The PDF file is only one page"* - in that case I'd try producing them from scratch. But that's merely a gut feeling.

Comment: @KevinBrown The PDF file contains only one page.

Comment: @mkl So you'd go with Approach 2. Any reason why?

Comment: If it's just one page (and not a complex layout), creation from scratch should be quick. And in such a case you have the advantage that you are not restricted by field dimensions. As said, it's more a gut feeling... If the page is so simple, though, i in your place would simply try it. Create both a routine for filling a template and creating a pdf from scratch, and call them in a loop and time that.